# Upload Imagem utilizando WebService C#

Tags: c#, java, android, web-service, imagem

gostaria de uma ajuda para saber qual a melhor forma para realizar upload de uma imagem utilizando webservice c#, já tentei diversas formar e vários exemplos porém não consegui.

Já tentei converter uma imagem para string base64, não tive sucesso. A forma para comunicação entre o webservice utilizei a biblioteca KSOAP2, tentei também JSON, HTTP POST... Alguns rodam porém não enviam foto 640 x 480.

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Olá @Whallas e bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Recomendo uma visita a [help] e uma leitura no [ask]. Reforce sua pergunta com um exemplo de código que tenha feito, ou algo para que os outros OPs possam lhe ajudar em cima do que já tenha feito.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer upload de um foto, você pode utilizar a anotação WebInvoke, que permite que você crie endpoints em WCF no formato REST. A seguir o trecho de código ao explicativo:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadPhoto/{fileName}/{description}", Method = "POST")] 
public void UploadPhoto(string fileName, string description, Stream fileContents) 
{ 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768]; 
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
    int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0; 
    do 
    { 
        bytesRead = fileContents.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead; 

        ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
    } while (bytesRead > 0); 

    // Save the photo on database. 
    using (DataAcess data = new DataAcess()) 
    { 
        var photo = new Photo() { Name = fileName, Description = description, Data = ms.ToArray(), DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow }; 
        data.InsertPhoto(photo); 
    } 

    ms.Close(); 
    Console.WriteLine("Uploaded file {0} with {1} bytes", fileName, totalBytesRead); 
}
```

Esse trecho vem de um exemplo completo com Client e Server para upload de imagens [MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Upload-files-using-a-REST-13f16af2/sourcecode?fileId=48404&pathId=787905472).

Talvez um implementação similar com WEB API seja mais confortável. Veja mais detalhes sobre [WEB API no site do asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

*Caso implemente o webservice (WCF ou WEB API) utilizando REST, será mais fácil enviar os dados independente da linguagem de origem*

Comment: Ele não está usando C#, mas sim Java – contextos iguais, ambientes diferentes. Além disso, respostas com apenas links não são agradáveis – eis o porquê d'eu negativar. [Leia mais aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links).

Comment: Ok, vou corrigir.

Comment: Maia não especifiquei que o cliente é uma aplicação android. Em android também funciona o seu exemplo? Como eu enviaria o Stream fileContents.

Comment: Sim, se você estiver utilizando um webservice REST, você consegue enviar um post de qualquer linguagem/plataforma. Encontrei um forma de implementar um post utilizando android SDK [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk/22803149#22803149), talvez ajude você.

Comment: Obrigado Maia, vou tentar aqui agora.